# in python code html has no breakdown and is included in <style> element

Tags: python, html

I want to create an html code in python.
I have an Excel file, from where I want to add some elements into the html code.

```
import openpyxl
from tkinter import filedialog
from helper import file_path

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename="uscities-travel-agency.xlsx")
sheet = wb.active
row_count = sheet.max_row
base_link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"
default_path = file_path()

print("Where do you want to save the files?")
print()
print("1- Default Location (Documents)")
print("2- Select Location")
location = input("Please select option 1 or 2 or leave for default >> ")

while location not in ["1", "2", ""]:
    location = input("(Try Again) Please select option 1 or 2 or leave for default >> ")

path = None
if location:
    if int(location) == 2:
        path = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir=default_path, title="Select Folder")


for i in range(1, row_count):
    city_c1 = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
    city_ascii_c2 = sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value
    state_keyword_c3 = sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value
    state_id_c4 = sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value
    state_name_c5 = sheet.cell(row=i, column=5).value
    county_fips_c6 = sheet.cell(row=i, column=6).value
    county_name_c7 = sheet.cell(row=i, column=7).value
    zips_c17 = sheet.cell(row=i, column=17).value
    html1_c18 = sheet.cell(row=2, column=19).value





    # print(city_c1, city_ascii_c2, state_id_c3, state_name_c4)

    file = open(f"{path if path else default_path}/{state_keyword_c3}-{city_c1}.html", "w")

    html_content = f'''
        <div style="display:flex; align-items:center; flex-direction:column;">

            {html1_c18} &#10
           
            <br></br>

           
            <h1>{city_c1} {state_keyword_c3} {state_name_c5} {county_fips_c6} {county_name_c7} {zips_c17}</h1>
            <br></br>
            <a href="https:wikipedia.org"><h4>   Click here for to search </h4></a>

           <h1> {city_c1} {state_keyword_c3} {state_name_c5} {county_fips_c6} {county_name_c7} {zips_c17}</h1>
           <h1> {city_c1} {state_keyword_c3} {state_name_c5} {county_fips_c6} {county_name_c7} {zips_c17}</h1>
                                  

        </div>
    '''

    file.write(html_content)
    file.close()
```

I have the following code, which is working fine when I don't include the [html1_c18] element. This
This element is a part of an hmtl code from my website.
When I now want to create the html code, I get the following result:
In the picture the yellow marked part is in the  element, but it should not. th  elements should be visible and outside the  element.

I have already tried it with `<br>; \n; &#10`
but it did not work.

Does someone know, how to fix this problem?

Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: you wrote your div into a `style` block in the head, so its trying to treat it as css

Comment: Thanks for that. 
I have tried to remove the following line
 <div style="display:flex; align-items:center; flex-direction:column;">
but the outcome is the same. It is still in the text/css. 
Unfortunatelly I'm not famliar with that and don't know yet how to solve this problem.